# Laravel Eloquent relationship with 4 tables manytomany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 4 tables

```
  Users
  id name
  1  test
  2  test 1

 Team
 id team_name 
 1  india
 2  Australia

 team_user
 user_id  team_id
 1           1
 1           2

 teamtype 
 team_id startdate    enddate  
  1        somedate    somedate
  1        somedate    somedate
  1        somedate    somedate
  2        somedate    somedate
  2        somedate    somedate
  2        somedate    somedate
```

Based on userid want to get  the team and all teamtype how can i achieve this using eloquent relationship in laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to User Model

```
public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
}
```

Then in your Team Model add

```
public function teamTypes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TeamType::class);
}
```

Then you can request User as

```
User::with('teams.teamTypes')->find($userId);
```

Comment: Thanks worked !! can i go more deeper when required like User::with('teams.teamTypes.anothertable.anothertable')->find($userId);